# Installing an app calling Google Play

Tags: android, web, installation

Does anyone know how to call google play from web to install an app on an android device?
I have the package name, the app name, the version name, the google account, the device id and the device model :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can launch an intent like this to direct users to the market page for a given application

```
//You can search for any application by swapping in the appropriate packagename
//after pname: 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.zxing.client.android"); 
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```